# Accessing file with relative path (previous folders) in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a folder which holds the JSON file of my Firebase db's, I have a .bat file in Windows which uploads the db's at once. Now I want to duplicate it to MAC.

This is the folder hierarchy:

- package-lock.json
- node_modules **(Folder)**
- GAME_NAME **(Folder)**

  - config.js
  - serviceAccount.json
  - Dev **(Folder)**

    - import_data.js
    - upload.sh -> This file i'm running
    - data **(Folder)**

      - Data-worldwide.json

**When running upload.sh:**

```
#! /bin/bash
node import_data.js
```

**import_data.js:**

```
// Imports
const firestoreService = require('..\..\node_modules\firestore-export-import');
const firebaseConfig = require('..\config.js');
const serviceAccount = require('..\serviceAccount.json');

// JSON To Firestore
const jsonToFirestore = async () => {
  try {
    console.log('Initialzing Firebase');
    await firestoreService.initializeApp(serviceAccount, firebaseConfig.databaseURL);
    console.log('Firebase Initialized');

    await firestoreService.restore('./data/Data-worldwide.json');
    console.log('Upload Success');
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

jsonToFirestore();
```

I'm keep getting this error:

```
xxxxxx@164 Dev % ./upload.sh
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:651
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '....
ode_modules
           irestore-export-import'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:649:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:575:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:705:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/xxxx/Dropbox/JSON Databases/GAME_NAME/Dev/import_data.js:2:26)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:799:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:810:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:606:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:3)
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:651
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '....
ode_modules
           irestore-export-import'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:649:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:575:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:705:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/xxxx/Dropbox/JSON Databases/GAME_NAME/Dev/import_data.js:2:26)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:799:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:810:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:606:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:3)
```

Comment: `require('firestore-export-import')` should be enough. Is the module installed?

Comment: What do you mean by "installed"? I just copied it from the Windows folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript string literals a `\` is an *escape character*.

To have a literal `\` in a string you need to escape it: `\\` … but Node.js generally uses UNIX-style directory separators (`/`) and not Windows ones anyway.